# How to implement this mechanism:

Tags: python

i want to implement a dynamic relation mechanism with python something like:

```
a:=10
b:=30
c:=a+b
print c
a+=20
print c
```

output:

```
40
60
```

c is always result of a+b.
so if a or b change, then c automatically updates value. i write a code in C# and do this by `set` and `get` mechanism. now want to translate it to python code for using in another program (FontLab Studio 5). I'm not so familiar with Python. does he have a `get,set` feature like C#? if not ho to implement one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New-style Python classes support [properties](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property).

Answer (score 4):

This is probably overkill, but it illustrates how you should create getters/setters in Python and achieve the functionality you want:

```
class Calc(object):
    def __init__(self, a = 0, b = 0):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self._a = value

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b

    @b.setter
    def b(self, value):
        self._b = value

    @property
    def c(self):
        return self._a + self._b

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.c)

calc = Calc()
calc.a = 1
calc.b = 2
print calc.c
calc.a += 10
print calc.c
```

If you don't want to make `a` and `b` a property, the code can be simplified:

```
class Calc(object):
    def __init__(self, a = 0, b = 0):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @property
    def c(self):
        return self.a + self.b

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.c)
```

Answer (score 3):

In your situation, c actually is a function which must be called.
You could use something like this:

```
a = 10
b = 30
c = lambda: a + b

print c()
a += 20
print c()
```

If you dislike that the method call is made explicit for c, you could use a general Calc object, which hides this implementation:

```
class Calc(object):
    def __init__(self):
        object.__setattr__(self,  '_params', dict())

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        param = self._params[name]
        if callable(param):
            return param()
        else:
            return param

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self._params[name] = value

    def __delattr__(self, name):
        del self._params[name]
```

And then you could do:

```
c = Calc()
c.a = 10
c.b = 30
c.c = lambda: c.a + c.b

print c.c
c.a += 20
print c.c
```

Comment: +1. I like your 1st approach. c is a not a variable, why all the make-up?

Comment: But, why don't you simply do `self._params = {}` in the second example. It's not an old-style class yet it smells like an old style class with that `__init__`.

Comment: @muhuk: If I would have done 'self._params = {}' in '__init__', then that would have resulted in 'Calc.__setattr__' handling that command. And '__setattr__' would call '__setattr__', going into infinite recursion.
Using 'object.__setattr__' allows the initial creation of '_params', after which it can be used normally without the '__setattr__', '__getattr__' or '__delattr__' handling '_params'.

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
class C:
  def __init__(self):
    self.x = 0
    self.y = 0

  def get(self):
    return self.x + self.y

  def __str__(self):
    return self.__unicode__()

  def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.get())

c = C()
c.x = 1
print c
c.y =2
print c
```

With new style classes and annotations you can probably make it better.